# drupal module redirect destination issue

Tags: drupal, redirect, hook

I am working on yet another module idea. This module is simply supposed to redirect a user automatically to a specified node like in the following example code:

```
  function test_module_init(){
    drupal_goto('node/100');
  }
```

The code is a mere example. But, the very really problem is the code keeps executing until the browser returns a "too many redirects" error message.

I understand why this is happening. What I need help with is the best hook to place my drupal_goto code so it executes once instead of the multiple times it currently does in hook_init.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do something like this:

```
 function test_module_init() {
    if(isset($_GET['q') && $_GET['q'] == 'node/100') {
       // skip goto statement
       return;
    }
    drupal_goto('node/100');
 }
```

Comment: not in this case. I am setting up a module which will detect the organic group a user belongs in and always redirect the user to said group. This way the user will only very see the group page he belongs in and no other node

Answer (score 0):

The init hook  you wrote fires on every page load including when you are on node/100.  That's why you're getting a redirect.  So the page is redirecting to itself.  You really only need to redirect if you're not already on node/100.   You can find this info in $_GET['q'] if you need to.

You don't need a different hook you just need to make sure that you don't call the drupal_goto if you're already on the destination page.